# Reset ipywidget Fileupload button after upload of the files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget, ipywidgets

I am trying to have the Upload(N) button of the FileUpload widget from Ipywidgets to reset the number N after i uploaded some files, but I'm not sure how. I am using Jupiter notebook with:

```
uploader=widgets.FileUpload(
    accept='*.csv',  # Accepted file extension e.g. '.txt', '.pdf', 'image/*', 'image/*,.pdf'
    multiple=True  # True to accept multiple files upload else False
)

def update_list_files(*args):
    global glob_list_f            #if i make the variable global then i can take it out of the function.
    glob_list_f = list(uploader.value.keys()) 

    
uploader.observe(update_list_files, 'value')
uploader
```

If I select 3 files it yields :
[Upload(3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkFvd.png)

Now If I select 3 other files it yields:
[Upload(6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7vDt.png)

The wanted behaviour would be Upload(3) again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I need to upload file again. I use next logic to reset button file upload state:

Click handling Function:

```
def button_click_func(change):
 # ... business logic

  upload_alg.value.clear()  # <--- clear saved value in cache
  upload_alg._counter=0     # <--- reset counter to visualize
```

Connect handler:

```
upload_file_button.observe(button_click_func, 'value')
```